# Android welcome screen waiting too long?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm new in Android development, every time when i try to start mine application, i need to wait very long?
I have low PC perfomance, but i see that peoples with much faster PC's has same problems.

Android star momently, but just this "Welcome" i wait to long.

PC main configuration:
Windows 7 Ultimate x86
-1024 mb RAM, 512 goes to ADK, i also tried with 256mb
-512 NVidia 6150
-2.0GHZ AMD Sempron

I use 2.7' QVGA API 17 Android, when i use API 7 or 8 i have some errors, i forget currently what problem is, but if is nessesery i will check.

Console out:

```
[2013-06-16 14:29:52 - Numerology] ------------------------------
[2013-06-16 14:29:52 - Numerology] Android Launch!
[2013-06-16 14:29:52 - Numerology] adb is running normally.
[2013-06-16 14:29:53 - Numerology] Performing com.nezic.numerology.Main activity launch
[2013-06-16 14:29:54 - Numerology] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AVD1'
[2013-06-16 14:29:54 - Numerology] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD1'
[2013-06-16 14:30:15 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
[2013-06-16 14:30:15 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
[2013-06-16 14:30:15 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-06-16 14:30:15 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-06-16 14:30:15 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-06-16 14:30:15 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-06-16 14:30:15 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-06-16 14:30:15 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-06-16 14:30:15 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-06-16 14:30:15 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-06-16 14:30:19 - Emulator] emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
[2013-06-16 14:30:19 - Emulator] 
[2013-06-16 14:30:21 - Numerology] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-06-16 14:30:21 - Numerology] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

This is what i wait too long.......

[image: android]

Thank.

Comment: Do you mean Emulator of SDK too long or actual application. Well you have too low ram just 1GB, but yes Emulator take time to boot up, real andriod will be much faster than this.

Comment: @SumitGupta
see answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you close emulator every time after an execution?

> Don't close it.
>
> Press home button and just minimize it.

Every time you start an emulator, The Android OS has to be loaded. That's what you are seeing there.

Comment: wow i didn't know that, thanks now will be much faster.
I tried that, but my application was not refreshed, also i try to build project but with no success...

Comment: @user1814358 It is not refreshed only in case if it is old build (also, the app's activity should be in foreground in android). If you will make clean and then build your app again it will reinstall your app in android and will run new installed apk with it main activity.

Answer (score 1):

You should not close and run again emulator each time. Just launch your app from Eclipse without closing emulator.

Answer (score 0):

try to check the Launch from snapshot
[see here](http://tools.android.com/recent/emulatorsnapshots)